# Keeping selection with onmouseup event

Tags: javascript

Im experimenting with range in javascript;

```
function matej()
{var x=window.getSelection();
 var renge=x.getRangeAt(0);
  var g=document.createElement("span");
 renge.surroundContents(g);


}

window.onmouseup=matej;
```

this thing does it job , but the selected text lose its selection .
How can i keep that selection? Here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/fduw8mor/1/

Comment: Browse through the answers of this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not as easy at it first seems. You might want to consider browsing through (or using) a library like [rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/). I've used it in the past with success.

Look at the [ClassApplier Docs](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule) in particular. The basic strategy is to detect all the textnodes in a selected range and apply a class to them so they appear to still be selected. You can style it to look just like the user-agent selection styles if you want.